# Unsure on What T-Test to Use

Tags: r, t-test, percentage

This is is my first post on this forum - I hope it's in the right place!

I am currently working on the analysis for a piece of coursework and was looking for some help with statistical test choice, please.

I have all my study data in a table. Am analysing the data using R/R Studio.

**Background**: The study is looking at how categorical interference influences levels of memory. There are 24 participants.

Participants were shown a series of images for 3 seconds each and asked to remember them. Then after a short break, they were presented with an old/new recognition task - one image flashed up on the screen at a time and the participant had to press 'left' if they thought the image had been seen before, and right if they thought it was novel image.

One part of my analysis requires me to see if the **percetange of correct responses** is **significantly different** for when the image presented at testing was **old** or **new**.

```
            Percentage Correct                             
 Old Images          48.79032                           
 New Images          79.73790           


            Total No. Correct                                           
 Old Images              4356                                        
 New Images              7119
```

So from this can see that when presented with a novel image, participants correctly identified it as a new image 79% of the time. But when presented with an old image, only 48% of participants realised they had seen the image before.

However, I am unsure as to which type of t-test I should be using to see whether the difference between the 48.79% and 79.74% is statistically significant. Would someone be able to give me some advice, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. Note that t-test is a fairly specific term for comparing two normally distributed numerical variables (there are not many types of t-test). Yours data are categorical (only two fixed options - correct/incorrect), so the simplest solution is likely Pearson's chi-squared test, for more fidelity and to be able to take other variables into account, you may want to read on *Binomial regression* with either *Generalized linear models* or *Multilevel models* (the latter are more powerful, but also a bit harder to grasp).

Comment: Would a paired samples t-test not be appropriate then? I thought t-test was the way to go because I'm comparing the means between two categorical variables (old and new images)? "A t-test requires two variables; one must be categorical and have exactly two levels, and the other must be quantitative and be estimable by a mean." So for me the categorical variable with two levels is image type - old or new. And the other (estimable by mean) is percentage of correct answers?

Comment: Paired t-test is not appropriate for this case I think you got confused by the terminology - the "categorical variable" means you have two groups of observations (each of which is normally distributed) - statistics can be hard to penetrate and hypothesis testing is especially confusing. I suggest you read some accessible introductory text to statistics such as *McKillup - Statistics Explained: An Introductory Guide for Life Scientists* or a good online guide. It will save you a lot of trouble in the long run :-)

Comment: Ah okay thank you for clarifying that. In which case then, if I'm using a Chi-Square goodness of fit test. My observed values are 4356 for Old images and 7119 for New images. But how would I calculate my expected values? Would these by the expected values of getting one getting one trial based on chance? 50/50?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to account for different individuals having different retentivity, than you could take your absolute numbers and compute McNemar's Test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test

If your statistical abilities go beyond that, you should consider a binomial mixed effects model with old/new as fixed effect and individual as random effect.